# Search only delivers media items after Sitecore Update

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

We updated our Sitecore CMS from version 6.3 to 6.6 SP2. This Sitecore version has the Intranet Module installed. Everything is working fine, but the Lucene Search doesn't seem to work properly.

There are two indexes defined. One for the whole content tree and one for the media library. The search only delivers results with media items (images, PDFs), but no pages. With the tool Luke I'm able to look into the indexes and I see the items there. But they are not in the search results on the website anymore.

I rebuilt the search indexes using the Sitecore Control Panel, but that didn't help.

As I said, it was working fine on Sitecore 6.3, but not on the updated 6.6 SP2.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would help to get clarified what "not working proberly" manifests as?

Comment: Added more information to the first post :)

Comment: Shifting from 6.3 to 6.6 also shifts the Lucene version and related configuration. The Lucene update introduces breaking changes, so most bespoke code would need re-visiting. At first, I would double check that all lucene/index related configuration has actually been correctly updated. Second step would be to scan the logs for Lucene related exceptions and warnings.

Comment: How do you select your index? it looks like your searching in the "Media items index" instead of the "full tree index"...

Comment: Both the content and the media index are configured in the web.config.

Comment: I usually debug to check which index am I opening and convert the Lucene query to string. This string can be executed against Luke and from there check what´s wrong.

Comment: Check your index configuration and make sure `<Root>/sitecore/content</Root>` and not set just to your media folder

Comment: I double checked the configurations and all looks good. And the search was working on 6.3.

Comment: I just checked the index with Luke and compared it to the backup before the update. The index is missing 3 fields: _sclsMedia, _sclsSearchable and _scLang. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post about [Troubleshooting Sitecore Lucene search and indexing](https://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/troubleshooting-sitecore-lucene-search-and-indexing/) .

In shortcut:

- Check if items are indexed correctly either using [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/).
- Check if `MatchAll` query return page items:

  ```
  SearchManager.GetIndex("your_index_name").CreateSearchContext()
      .Search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), int.MaxValue)
      .FetchResults(0, int.MaxValue).Select(r => r.GetObject<Item>())
  ```
- Check included templates:

  ```
  <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the 3 missing fields _sclsMedia, _sclsSearchable and _scLang in the Content Lucene Index that are causing the search not to function. So I removed the 3 fields from the code in my solution and now I get search results again.

The question is why were those 3 fields lost during the update from Sitecore 6.3 to 6.6.